# How do I write this as a context manager?

Tags: python

The race-condition-free way of updating a variable in redis is:

```
r = redis.Redis()
with r.pipeline() as p:
    while 1:
        try:
            p.watch(KEY)
            val = p.get(KEY)
            newval = int(val) + 42
            p.multi()
            p.set(KEY, newval)
            p.execute()  # raises WatchError if anyone else changed KEY
            break
        except redis.WatchError:
            continue  # retry
```

this is significantly more complex than the straight forward version (which contains a race-condition):

```
r = redis.Redis()
val = r.get(KEY)
newval = int(val) + 42
r.set(KEY, newval)
```

so I thought a context manager would make this easier to work with, however, I'm having problems...

My initial idea was

```
with update(KEY) as val:
    newval = val + 42
    somehow return newval to the contextmanager...?
```

there wasn't an obvious way to do the last line, so I tried::

```
@contextmanager
def update(key, cn=None):
    """Usage::

            with update(KEY) as (p, val):
                newval = int(val) + 42
                p.set(KEY, newval)

    """
    r = cn or redis.Redis()
    with r.pipeline() as p:
        while 1:
            try:
                p.watch(key)  # --> immediate mode
                val = p.get(key)
                p.multi()  # --> back to buffered mode
                yield (p, val)
                p.execute()  # raises WatchError if anyone has changed `key`
                break  # success, break out of while loop
            except redis.WatchError:
                pass  # someone else got there before us, retry.
```

which works great as long as I don't catch a `WatchError`, then I get

```
  File "c:\python27\Lib\contextlib.py", line 28, in __exit__
    raise RuntimeError("generator didn't stop")
RuntimeError: generator didn't stop
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because the real code needs `newval` to be `max(float(val or '0.0') + 7, time.time())` :-)

Comment: This doesn't really map cleanly to a context manager, use a function (see poke's answer).

Comment: @PavelAnossov: I don't agree, a context manager seems to present the right interface.

Comment: @RikPoggi the `with` statement does look pretty, but I think Python needs more expressive context managers for this to work (although I'd be very happy to be proved wrong).  @poke's answer both works, and is very straight forward.. the only issue is that Python's syntax is not very friendly to callback code (and some people do not like `lambda`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that you yield multiple times (when the task is repeated) but a context manager is only entered once (the `yield` is just a syntactic sugar for the `__enter__` method). So as soon as the yield can be executed multiple times, you have a problem.

I’m not prefectly sure how to solve this in a good way, and I can’t test it either, so I’m only giving some suggestions.

First of all, I would avoid yielding the rather internal `p`; you should yield some object that is specifically made for the update process. For example something like this:

```
with update(KEY) as updater:
    updater.value = int(updater.original) + 42
```

Of course this still doesn’t solve the multiple yields, and you cannot yield that object earlier as you won’t have the original value at that point either. So instead, we could specify a delegate responsible for the value updating instead.

```
with update(KEY) as updater:
    updater.process = lambda value: value + 42
```

This would store a function inside the yielded object which you can then use inside the context manager to keep trying to update the value until it succeeded. And you can yield that updater from the context manager early, before entering the while loop.

Of course, if you have made it this far, there isn’t actually any need for a context manager left. Instead, you can just make a function:

```
update(key, lambda value: value + 42)
```

Comment: Snooping at the [doc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis/) it would appear that the `r.transaction` function is, more or less, doing that.